# How to uninstall Jenkins in Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I have a problem with Homebrew especially with Jenkins formula.

```
$ brew update;brew upgrade
Already up-to-date.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
jenkins 1.598
==> Upgrading jenkins
...
  /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/1.598: 6 files, 65M, built in 7 seconds
$ brew uninstall jenkins --force
Uninstalling jenkins...
$ brew cleanup
```

Ok, I strongly believe that I completely uninstalled the formula. The problem is that the Jenkins formula installs every time when I do `brew update;brew upgrade`.

How can I uninstall Jenkins completely?